# How to skip metadata in Kafka connect Filepulse?

Tags: json, apache-kafka, header, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Kafka Connect FilePulse to get data from files. I have a problem in that I want to skip multiple lines from the header of a file. For example, my JSON file like:

```
Metadata1
Metadata2

{
a: 2
}
```

How can I skip 2 first line?

My config:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "config": {
      "connector.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.source.FilePulseSourceConnector",
      "filters": "ParseJSON",
      "filters.ParseJSON.type":"io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.filter.JSONFilter",
      "filters.ParseJSON.source":"message",
      "filters.ParseJSON.merge":"true",
      "filters.ParseJSON.explode.array":"true",
      "skip.headers": "2", 
      "fs.cleanup.policy.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.clean.LogCleanupPolicy",
      "fs.cleanup.policy.triggered.on":"COMMITTED",
      "fs.listing.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.LocalFSDirectoryListing",
      "fs.listing.directory.path":"/tmp/kafka-connect/examples/",
      "fs.listing.filters":"io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.filter.RegexFileListFilter",
      "fs.listing.interval.ms": "10000",
      "file.filter.regex.pattern":".*\\.json$",
      "topic": "json",
      "tasks.reader.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.reader.LocalBytesArrayInputReader",
      "tasks.file.status.storage.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.state.KafkaFileObjectStateBackingStore",
      "tasks.file.status.storage.bootstrap.servers": "broker:29092",
      "tasks.file.status.storage.topic": "connect-file-pulse-status-1",
      "tasks.file.status.storage.topic.partitions": 10,
      "tasks.file.status.storage.topic.replication.factor": 1,
      "tasks.max": 1
    }
}
```

I have to try `skip.headers = 2` in the configuration but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The `skip.headers` config property is only available for the `RowFileInputReader` (here you are using the `LocalBytesArrayInputReader`). Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to read a JSON file while filtering certain lines, unless you develop your own Reader.